# Checking if internet connection over WiFi or mobile data available

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I'm using the following piece of code to check if a phone is connected to internet (either WiFi or mobile data):

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
    if (capabilities != null) {
        if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)) {
            return true;
        } else if (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)) {
            return true;
        } else return capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET);
    }
} else {
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (activeNetworkInfo != null) && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

It could be the case that a phone is connected to WiFi but not to internet. For my use case I assume that when it is connected to WiFi or mobile network (with mobile data enabled) that internet will be available.

Is this piece of code ok? Especially, does `activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()` also test for mobile data or only WiFi? I'm targeting Android 7 to Android 10. Theoretically I could use the the piece of code in the if-clause also for devices below Android 10 I think.

Comment: Try using isConnectedOrConndcting corresponding to https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-status-type#java

Comment: @TarikWeiss What is the difference to isConnected? Would that also work?

Comment: @TarikWeiss Do you know the difference? I searched but did not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ask for this permission to the manifest.xml : android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

**In android, we can determine the internet connection
status easily by using WIFIMANAGER.**

```
private boolean LookForWifiOnAndConnected() {
WifiManager wifi_m = (WifiManager) 
 getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

if (wifi_m.isWifiEnabled()) { // if user opened wifi

    WifiInfo wifi_i = wifi_m.getConnectionInfo();

    if( wifi_i.getNetworkId() == -1 ){
        return false; // Not connected to any wifi device
    }
    return true; // Connected to some wifi device
}
else {
    return false; // user turned off wifi
}
```

}

// **check if mobile data on or off**

```
  boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try {
    Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
    Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
    // get the setting for "mobile data"
    mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Some problem accessible private API
    // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What is the difference to activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()? Would that also work?

Comment: Is reflection really recommended in Android? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, Android supports reflection.